# Uninstall MariaDB without removing databases

Tags: mariadb

I am running **MariaDB 10.3** on **Ubuntu 20.04**.
Now MariaDB is not running and one database in it.
Can I uninstall the MariaDB 10.3 retaining database?
My plan is that install a higher version of MariaDB and get back the existing database.
If so, which commands do I have to apply?

Comment: Dump the database (`mysqldump databaseName > file.sql`) , reinstall MariaDB, and import the database (`mysql databaseName < file.sql`). Is that what you need?

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution, uninstall MariaDB without deleting databases and reinstall it again.

```
sudo apt purge "mariadb*" -y
sudo apt autoremove -y
sudo apt-get install mariadb-server mariadb-client
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqldump -u [username] -p [DATABASE name] > [backup filename].sql

mysql -u [username] -p [DATABASE name] < [backup filename].sql
```

Comment: MariaDB service is not running because of mysqld.sock problem. MySQL dump command will not work.